# switch hex view to graph view on IDA

Tags: disassembly, ida

is anynonehere  familiar with IDA (disassembler) program? I've switched the graph view to hex view and for about an hour trying to switch it back with no luck.. no guide online says how to switch back..
If anynone knows the secret I'd like to know how.. really short in time.
thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

The space bar toggles between the graph view and disassembly view. Use the '-' and '+' keys to toggle between [proximity view](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1626.shtml) and disassembly view.

There doesn't seem to be a standard shortcut for going from the hex view to any of the other views, except for `CTRL+TAB` and `SHIFT+CTRL+TAB` which cycle through the open views (just as in most other programs).

Via the menu item `View > Open subviews > Disassembly` you can open a new disassembly window, should the old one have been closed accidentally. The menu item `Options > Shortcuts...` pulls up a dialog that shows all currently active keyboard shortcuts (i.e. those that are valid for the currently active view).